# Отменить фокус TextField при запуске

Tags: javafx

При запуске приложения JavaFX, происходит фокусировка на первом TextFielde. Как убрать автофокусировку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Код для избавление фокуса поля.**

Внутри `initialize()` контроллера:

```
названиеТекстовогоПоля.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

**Код для наведения фокуса на определенное поле.**

Внутри `initialize()` контроллера

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         названиеТекстовогоПоля.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Это решение работает только с AnchorPane? Пробовал с VBox - не заработало.

Comment: в сценбилдере anchorpane вроде не генерится автоматом

Comment: @Sergey обновил ответ. У меня генерится

Comment: названиеТекстовогоПоля.setFocusTraversable(false);
я так понимаю это надо запихнуть в Main, а если у меня сделано через fxml?

Comment: спс, вроде заработало. заимплементил интерфейс Initializable, реализовал метод initialize() в который запихнул названиеТекстовогоПоля.setFocusTraversable(false). а можно поставить фокус на определенное поле при запуске приложения?

Comment: @Sergey названиеТекстовогоПоля.setFocusTraversable(true)?(:

Comment: к сожалению не катит(((((

Comment: @Sergey дополнил ответ

Comment: огромное человеческое спасибо, все вышло

Comment: @Sergey да не за что) кстати, fx-приложения красивее в паре c css

Comment: буду изучать, недавно начал c JavaFx разбираться